# Retrieve scores for each document Neo4j Lucene, not just the order

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene, full-text-search, cypher

I have indexed the `title` property of a book node in Neo4j using the full-text capabilities of Lucene. 
When I want to search for a particular term(like `wars`) in a title across all nodes, I can do the following:

```
     IndexHits<Node> nodes = graphDb.index().forNodes("node_auto_index").query("title:wars");
     for (Node n : nodes) {
        //do something
     }
     nodes.close();
```

This returns the nodes sorted in order of some frequency score maintained by Lucene.

I would like to know the actual score associated to each of the nodes in the result. For example if the index internally looks as follows:

`wars -> id8:4, id3:3, id1:2`

I would like to return the corresponding scores 4,3 and 1 instead of just the ids.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
IndexHits<Node> hits = graphDb.index().forNodes("node_auto_index").query("title:wars");
while (hits.hasNext()) {
  Node node = hits.next();
  float weight = hits.currentScore();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a constant time method to retrieve the score given a term and a document id? For example `(wars,id1)=2`?